# Why isn't my table showing up? stuck right now

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to replicate a 1 rowed table with a form, such that when I press the '+' button - I would like another table form to drop down below it exactly the way it is - however, when I do that and add the same element as the table with the HTML code, I get something different...

I got screenshot images to the form below and after that I got the code indented -

[image]

[image]

the code for the above images is listed below - the first being the forms and the second being the javascript function

```
    <body>
        <form>

            <div id="container1">

<table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:12px width="900"">
<colgroup>
<col span="1">
</colgroup>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="company" size="3">Company:</label> <input type="text" id="company" name="company" maxlength="15" size="15">
</td>
<td valign="top">
<label for="position1" size="3">Position:</label> <input  type="text" id="position1" name="position1" maxlength="20" size="12"> </td> <td valign="top"><label for="tasks" size="3"> Tasks: </label></td><td> <textarea  id="tasks" name="tasks" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="1"></textarea></td>
<td valign="top"><label for="from1" size="3">  From: </label><input type="text" id="from1" name="from1" size="4" ></td> <td valign="top">To: <input type="text" id="to1" name="to1" size="4"> <td valign="top"><label for="location" size="3">Work Location: </label><input type="text" id="location" name="location" size="20" maxlength="25"><a href="#" id="Add1" onclick="aFields1()"> + </a><br></td>
</tr>
</table><br>               
            </div>

        </form>
    </body>
```

the javascipt code is posted below:

```
function aFields1(){
var container1 = document.getElementById("container1");
var table = document.createElement("table");

table.border=1; 
table.cellspacing=0;
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
var td = document.createElement("td");
td.valign = "top";

var label = document.createElement("label");
label.for = "company";
label.size = 3;
container1.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Company: "));
container1.appendChild(label);

var company = document.createElement("input");
company.type = "text";

company.id = "company";
company.name = "company";
company.size = 15;
company.maxlenth = 15;
//append the company input element to the td element
td.appendChild(company);

tr.appendChild(td);
table.appendChild(tr);
//append the td element to the container1 element
//container1.appendChild(tr);   
container1.appendChild(table);
```

Can anyone please tell me why the table is not showing up?

There should be a border with at least one cell with the company label and input bar INSIDE it - but as you can see from the image the Company label is on the top and the input bar with the border is below it...

where'd I go wrong? and why are the borders for the cell much much more different from what came out of the HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply clone the table row instead of creating every element from scratch. I've attached an example, however you might want to change/increment the ID's and Names after the cloning but before appending in order to make them unique. I'll leave that to you. In the future please make sure to properly indent your HTML and JavaScript.

FYI: Adding an ID to the tbody will make it easier to select.

```js
        function aFields1() {
         var lastTableRow = document.getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0].lastElementChild;
         var newRow = lastTableRow.cloneNode(true);
         document.getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0].appendChild(newRow);
        }
```

```html
    <body>
        <form>

            <div id="container1">

<table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:12px width="900"">
<colgroup>
<col span="1">
</colgroup>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="company" size="3">Company:</label> <input type="text" id="company" name="company" maxlength="15" size="15">
</td>
<td valign="top">
<label for="position1" size="3">Position:</label> <input  type="text" id="position1" name="position1" maxlength="20" size="12"> </td> <td valign="top"><label for="tasks" size="3"> Tasks: </label></td><td> <textarea  id="tasks" name="tasks" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="1"></textarea></td>
<td valign="top"><label for="from1" size="3">  From: </label><input type="text" id="from1" name="from1" size="4" ></td> <td valign="top">To: <input type="text" id="to1" name="to1" size="4"> <td valign="top"><label for="location" size="3">Work Location: </label><input type="text" id="location" name="location" size="20" maxlength="25"><a href="#" id="Add1" onclick="aFields1()"> + </a><br></td>
</tr>
</table><br>               
            </div>

        </form>
</body>
```